# Problem installing VCS module in python: Command error

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am trying to install VCS via ***pip3 install vcs*** but encountered this error:

```
Collecting vcs
 Using cached vcs-0.4.0.tar.gz (482 kB)
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: /Users/lyndz/opt/miniconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;         
 sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/39/z65bwzg92zbcj_9jhmv7pm2c0000gn/T/pip-install-
 lwcjhwsx/vcs/setup.py'"'"';      
 __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/39/z65bwzg92zbcj_9jhmv7pm2c0000gn/T/pip-install-     
 lwcjhwsx/vcs/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)
 (__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
 __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 
 /private/var/folders/39/z65bwzg92zbcj_9jhmv7pm2c0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-o6brd8bc
     cwd: /private/var/folders/39/z65bwzg92zbcj_9jhmv7pm2c0000gn/T/pip-install-lwcjhwsx/vcs/
Complete output (6 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/39/z65bwzg92zbcj_9jhmv7pm2c0000gn/T/pip-install-
 lwcjhwsx/vcs/setup.py", line 11
    except IOError, err:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------

 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for 
 full command output.
```

Any ideas on solving this?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: VCS was last maintained in 2013 and is clearly written in Python 2. I *don't* recommend forking the project because migrating unknown code to Python 3 is not just about `except` clauses and `print()` calls: it can be a *very* demanding job. And the fact that you are asking this question at all suggests that such a project is overambitious for your current level of Python skills.

Comment: yes.very true...im a newbie haha...thanks for this advise

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is because of python3 syntax which doesn't allow `except IOError, e`. You should fork that pip package in your Github and change that exception like below:

```
except IOError as err:
```